# filtering output of a recursive command

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find a shell command that returns the file names of files that contain other files that have the same name as theirs in a certain directory

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: for example, if we have a directory that contains a subdirectory that in its turn contains other files. here we want to know the names of the parent directories that contain subdirectories that have the same name as the parent directory. I tried something like (ls -R /etc | ...)

Comment: so given [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24418803/) you'd want to return `yes` and `yep` but not `no` (contains dir with same name but it is empty) or `nope` (no subdir with same name)?

Comment: the second part of what you said is closest for example if we have a directory called DIR which contains files (file1, file2, file3, DIR). the command will return the name of this directory (I mean by that DIR).

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be asking for is a command that finds files whose name is the same as that of their parent directory.

You can do that using GNU `find`, with a regular expression match that uses a backreference to the preceding path component e.g.

```
find path/to/somedir -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([^/]*)/\1$'
```

If you specifically want to find plain *files* that match their parent (excluding matching sub*directories*) you can add `-type f` to the predicate list (or if you want to *only* find subdirectories, use `-type d`).

To illustrate, given

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
├── baz
│   ├── baz
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── foo
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

3 directories, 10 files
```

then

```
$ find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([^/]*)/\1$'
./baz/baz
```

If you want to print only the name (rather than the full path), you can use a `-printf`

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([^/]*)/\1$' -printf '%f\n'
```